# Geographical segmentation mismatch

Tags: python, geospatial, rasterio

I am doing a [project](https://github.com/eduardogfma/ml_fire/blob/master/regionalSegmentation/FWI_geographicalSegmentation.ipynb) where we need to segment a geospatial data. The data set comprises the Fire Weather Index (FWI) -- a fire hazard classification system -- for the whole world from the 1980's to 2018. We want to segment data according to the NUTS (or GADM) in order to be able to predict and investigate possible patterns over time.

We have to our disposal:

- the FWI dataset (resolution: 0.7 degrees ~ 80x80 Km)
- the NUTS (and GADM) shape files

Our methodology was the following:

1. import shape files with geopandas
2. import the FWI dataset with xarray
3. rasterize the shapefiles ([adapted code](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/501#issuecomment-126461466))
4. get FWI data segmented by NUTS/GADM

A couple of issues were identified:

- not all the areas in the region of interest were segmented correctly
- there appears to be an offset in between the NUTS/GADM and FWI points available

The functions used are as follows:

```py
def transform_from_latlon(lat, lon):
    lat = np.asarray(lat)
    lon = np.asarray(lon)
    trans = Affine.translation(lon[0], lat[0])
    scale = Affine.scale(lon[1] - lon[0], lat[1] - lat[0])
    return  trans * scale

def rasterize(shapes, coords, latitude='lat', longitude='lon',
              fill=np.nan, **kwargs):
    """Rasterize a list of (geometry, fill_value) tuples onto the given
    xray coordinates. This only works for 1d latitude and longitude
    arrays.
    """
    transform = transform_from_latlon(coords[latitude], coords[longitude])

    out_shape = (len(coords[latitude]), len(coords[longitude]))
    #requires the features library from rasterio
    raster = features.rasterize(shapes, out_shape=out_shape,
                                fill=fill, transform=transform, all_touched=True, dtype=float, **kwargs)
    spatial_coords = {latitude: coords[latitude], longitude: coords[longitude]}
    return xr.DataArray(raster, coords=spatial_coords, dims=(latitude, longitude))
```

The described segmentation process results in the following picture.

[image: Segmentation result.]

As can be seen there seems to exist an offset between the segmented data and the actual map areas. Moreover, there are some islands that are not even captured by the segmentation.